# CSS Media Query not generating any response

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the title-image static when the screen size is less than `1052px` so that it occupies the full width of the viewport but the styles get applied only when screen size gets less than `992px`. This is from the Angela Yu's course of Web Development.

```css
.title-image {
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 25%;
}

media (max-width: 1052px) {
  .title-image {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>tindog</title>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b2df711599.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- JS and Jquery -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Title -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark download-button"><i class="fa-brands fa-apple"></i>
            Download</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-light download-button"><i
              class="fa-brands fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img class="title-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="iphone-mockup">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is what it looks like, please help me with it.

[image]

Comment: `media` needs to be `@media` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1052px) {
    .title-image {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

You've also set the columns to always be half the screen width, you might also need to add col-12 along with col-lg-6 so that on smaller screens it goes full width

Answer (score 0):

Change your media query to:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1052px) {
  .title-image {
    position: static;
  }
}
```